# How can you stop vscode terminal running some script at the beginning?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I launch the terminal in VSCode within a certain directory, a specific script is executed every time at the beginning.

I'm trying to figure out the possible cause of this behavior. The script that gets executed is a single line saying "pyenv shell 3.10.1" and I suspect I configured it at some point, but I can't remember where. There are no configuration files like .vscode within the directory. Opening the VSCode terminal in the home directory, or in directories above or below this one, doesn't trigger the script. Additionally, running the regular macOS terminal doesn't execute the script either. The vscode version I'm using is Version 1.85.1 on macOS 14.2.1 (23C71). Any insights into what might be causing this would be appreciated. In particular, where else could this configuration be documented outside of the .vscode directory within the local directory?

Comment: in your global settings file: Open the JSON file and examine.